# Python SpiDev TypeError when trying to recieve and then send data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to receive data on my Raspberry Pi from one micro-controller that is sending a byte, and then sending that data off to another micro-controller. However, I get the following error:

```
resp = spi.xfer(list) TypeError: Non-Int/Long value in arguments: b66deb70.
```

I have tried changing the list value to hex and populating the list with many more values to see if that would help, but no luck. Not a ton of info on how to receive data properly online through SPI. Does anyone know how to resolve this error by creating the list properly?

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.open(0, 1)
spi.max_speed_hz = 1
spi.mode = 0

count = 0
list = [0x00, 0x00]
try:
    while True:
        list[0] = count # update our count variable (single element in a list)
        count = spi.readbytes(1) # read data being recieved from 1st microcontroller
        print(count)
        resp = spi.xfer(list) # send the data to the 2nd microcontroller 
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    spi.close()
```

Comment: The first time your loop runs, the first element in your list is set to zero. Then `count` is set to some byte value, which might be causing the issue the second time your loop runs.  `xfer()` expects a list of ints

Comment: @Mazzone how many ints should the list have? I'm just trying to send a byte and recieve a byte, and I cannot find many examples on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

`spidev` checks for validity of the values in the input list via `PyLong_Check`, (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)), which sadly doesn't accept certain things that you might hope it would as valid values. Worse, the error message does not really tell you anything useful.

I think your issue is that with `count = spi.readbytes(1)`, count is being set to a list, not an integer. If you change to

```
count = spi.readbytes(1)[0]
```

I would expect your code to work!